# *** caught segfault *** address 0x2aaeb4b6f440, cause 'memory not mapped' when Fortran is called by R

Tags: r, fortran, hpc

I have a very specific error so googling wasn't helpful and I'm sorry I don't know how to provide a simple producible example for this issue. The code below runs perfectly on my local machine but on the HPC it is producing this error:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x2ad718ba0440, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: array(.Fortran("hus_vertical_interpolation", m = as.integer(DIM[1]),     n = as.integer(DIM[2]), o = as.integer(DIM[3]), p = as.integer(DIM[4]),     req = as.integer(length(req_press_levels)), hus_on_model_level = as.numeric(spec_hum_data[]),     pres = as.numeric(req_press_levels), pressure_full_level = as.numeric(pressure[]),     hus_on_press_level = as.numeric(output_array[]))$hus_on_press_level,     dim = output_DIM)
 2: Specific_humidity_afterburner(spec_hum_file = q_nc.files[x],     req_press_levels = required_PLev)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

The code is supposed to:

1. Loop over a vector of NetCDF files and pass the filename `spec_hum_file` to function `Specific_humidity_afterburner`.
2. The function reads the NetCDF file, extract data pass to the first compiled subroutine, do the math and return the values.
3. Take the result, pass it to another FORTRAN subroutine and return the second result.
4. Write the second result to a new NetCDF file.

The error occurs in step 3. The R function is:

```
Specific_humidity_afterburner<-function(spec_hum_file,req_press_levels){
  
  require(ff)
  require(ncdf4)
  require(stringi)
  require(DescTools)
  library(stringr)
  library(magrittr)
  #1============================================================================ 
  #Reading data from netCDF file
  #2============================================================================ 
  #Reading other variables
  #3============================================================================
  # First Fortran subroutine 
  #4============================================================================
  
  #load vertical interpolate subroutine for specific humidity
  dyn.load("spec_hum_afterburner/vintp2p_afterburner_hus.so")
  #check
  is.loaded("hus_vertical_interpolation")
  
  DIM<-dim(spec_hum_data)
  
  output_DIM<-c(DIM[1],DIM[2],length(req_press_levels),DIM[4])
  
  output_array<-ff(array(0.00,dim =output_DIM),dim =output_DIM)
  
  result<- array(.Fortran("hus_vertical_interpolation",
                          m=as.integer(DIM[1]),
                          n=as.integer(DIM[2]),
                          o=as.integer(DIM[3]),
                          p=as.integer(DIM[4]),
                          req = as.integer(length(req_press_levels)),
                          pres=as.numeric(req_press_levels),
                          pressure_full_level=as.numeric(pressure[]),
                          hus_on_model_level=as.numeric(spec_hum_data[]),
                          hus_on_press_level=as.numeric(output_array[]))$hus_on_press_level,
                 dim =output_DIM)
  
  DIMNAMES<-dimnames(spec_hum_data)
  
  DIMNAMES[["lev"]]<-req_press_levels
  
  Specific_humidity<- ff(result, dim = output_DIM,
                         dimnames =DIMNAMES )
  rm(result)
  
  #5============================================================================
  # Writing NetCDF file of the interpolated values 
}
```

Fortran subroutine:

```
subroutine hus_vertical_interpolation(m,n,o,p,req,pres, &
    pressure_full_level,hus_on_model_level,hus_on_press_level)
implicit none
integer :: m,n,o,p,req
integer :: x,y,s,t,plev
double precision :: pres(req),hus_on_model_level(m,n,o,p)
double precision :: pressure_full_level(m,n,o,p)
double precision :: delta_hus,delta_p,grad_hus_p,diff_p
double precision, intent(out) :: hus_on_press_level(m,n,req,p)
real :: arg = -1.0,NaN
NaN= sqrt(arg)
do plev=1,req
 do t=1,p 
  do x=1,m
   do y=1,n 
    do s=1,o    
!above uppest level
    if(pres(plev) .LT. pressure_full_level(x,y,1,t)) then 
     hus_on_press_level(x,y,plev,t) = NaN
    end if 
! in between levels
    if(pres(plev) .GE. pressure_full_level(x,y,s,t) .AND. pres(plev) .LE. &
     pressure_full_level(x,y,s+1,t) ) then 
     delta_hus = hus_on_model_level(x,y,s,t) - hus_on_model_level(x,y,s+1,t)
     delta_p = log(pressure_full_level(x,y,s,t))&
     - log(pressure_full_level(x,y,s+1,t))
     grad_hus_p = delta_hus /delta_p
     diff_p = log(pres(plev)) - log(pressure_full_level(x,y,s,t))
     hus_on_press_level(x,y,plev,t) = hus_on_model_level(x,y,s,t)&
     + grad_hus_p * diff_p 
    end if  
! extrapolation below the ground  
    if(pres(plev) .GT. pressure_full_level(x,y,o,t)) then
     hus_on_press_level(x,y,plev,t) = hus_on_model_level(x,y,o,t)
    end if
    end do 
   end do 
  end do    
 end do
end do   
end subroutine hus_vertical_interpolation
```

Fortran subroutine was compiled with:

```
gfortran -fPIC -shared -ffree-form vintp2p_afterburner_hus.f90 -o vintp2p_afterburner_hus.so
```

The error behaviour is unpredictable for example, can happen at index 1, 2, 8, .. etc of the loop. We have tried to hand over the big array to the Fortran subroutine as the last variable, it minimized the occurrence of the error.
Also, the NetCDF files have a size of ~2GB. Another point to mention, The modules are built with EasyBuild so conflicts are not probable as HPC support team stated. We have tried many solutions as far as we know and no progress!

Comment: Do you get any useful information when compiling the Fortran subroutine with runtime checks enabled?

Comment: I don't get any information back. I used  `-fcheck=all` option

Comment: The hit was really helpful! Now I see the error `At line 22 of file vintp2p_afterburner_hus.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '36' of dimension 3 of array 'pressure_full_level' above upper bound of 35`. I corrected it.  any Thanks!